# Concurrent Dictionary with Get and Private Set - C#

Tags: c#

I have a private `ConcurrentDictionary` as shown below:

```
#region Private Fields
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> properties = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
#endregion
```

I have a public property with a `get` as shown below:

```
#region Properties
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Properties { get { return properties; } }
#endregion
```

I thought this was valid but in my tests I can still add things to the dictionary via the public `Properties` property with `TryAdd` etc.

I have a method in the same class called `AddProperties` that takes the `key` and `value` and stores them in the private dictionary, but I wanted the `Properties` to be read only in other classes.

Comment: The property *is* read-only - you can't modify the property value. But that's not the same as not being able to mutate the object that the property value refers to. You could change the property type to `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>`, although the caller could still cast back to `ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>`. Also note that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core - I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is expose your dictionary as an [`IReadOnlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-5.0). Right now classes can only `get` the `Properties` dictionary, but once they have it can do what they want with it. Instead, you can expose your [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-5.0) as readonly by casting it a `IReadOnlyDictionary` like so:

```cs
public IReadonlyDictionary<string, string> Properties { get { return (IReadOnlyDictionary) properties } }
```

Now the classes accessing that property can only read from the dictionary. But be aware, they could technically cast it back to a `ConcurrentDictionary` and modify it again

---

**Edit:** Just saw that [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338509/concurrent-dictionary-with-get-and-private-set-c-sharp/65338657#comment115512182_65338509) stating the same while I was writing this answer

Comment: Great thanks both, is it `IReadOnlyDictionary` or `IReadonlyDictionary`? Either are asking me to install a nuget `System.Runtime` is the right?

Comment: Its `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>` in the cast,  but the Visual Studio is telling me the cast is redundant.  Just had to change my Interface but it seems to be working without the cast.  I'll also bare in mind about it being cast back to a `ConcurrentDictionary` too.  Thanks

Comment: @user1574598 yup, it's `IReadOnlyDictionary` with the uppercase `O`, my bad. And yes, the cast is unnecessary, I just added it to explicitly show what exactly is going on